# Google Analytics v4 and tracking installs in different apks

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I'm new to this GA thing, and the guide on the official website (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) is not really clear to me.

For my first app I want some simple statistics: when people install the app or delete it, do they return to it after installing.

Also I'd like to make several apk's (not only for Google Play, but also for third-party websites) and see stats for each app (I've heard you can add some kind of markers for that).

I have the required permissions in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I also have a global_tracker.xml but it's not yet functional:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">
<integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>

<!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

<!-- The screen names that will appear in reports -->

<!--  The following value should be replaced with correct property id. -->
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-hidden-2</string>
```

What else do I need to add and where? Is there some better guide rather that the one I linked above?

Answer (score 0):

To track installations on Android you need to enable campaign tracking by registering CampaignTrackingService and CampaignTrackingReceiver in your ApplicationManifest.xml:

```
<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
          android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

To also track applications referring your application (like browser link launching your application) you will also need to either enable automatic activity tracking with a call to `tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true)` or manually call  `tracker.setCampaignParamsOnNextHit(activity.getIntent.getData()`. If you expect your app will run on Android API 11 or earlier (this is Android 3.0 Honeycomb) you also need to manually call `analytics.reportActivityStart(this)` from each `Activity.onStart()` and `analytics.reportActivityStop(this)` from each `Activity.onStop()` of your application activities.

Web sites don't actually distribute your app. They only link to Google Play store entry. You need to provide the web site with the URL to install your application. The URL you provide must include "referrer" parameter with your campaign parameters.

There is detailed campaign tracking devguide on Google Analytics developer site: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns

There is URL builder at the end of the devguide that you can use to generate your download URL.